# Are Twilio video and client Javascript SDK cross-platform?

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-api

I wanted to know if I can use Twilio Video or Client JavaScript SDK for both web and mobile development.

I have no background in iOS or Android Development so it would be good if I can just use JavaScript SDK use react native or wrap it in Cordova.

Comment: What's the question, please? Where's the code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While we have no plans to create wrappers of the native SDKs for Cordova, it is possible that the community will provide this. They have in the past for Twilio Client. I don't currently know of any projects though.

On Android, you should be able to just use the [JavaScript SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/sdks#javascript-sdk) as Chrome on Android supports WebRTC. On iOS you don't have so much luck as Safari doesn't support it.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: is there any update or change in twilio video? I'm also building a react native app and was wondering if twilio video would be the right fit?

Comment: There is a community built React Native wrapper for Twilio video here: https://github.com/gaston23/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc. The author actually mentioned this as an issue on one of our repos and the response was that we will be dedicating resources to this sort of thing soon too. (https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-objc/issues/30#issuecomment-261836152). That's all I know for now.

Comment: thanks, @philnash I did get in touch with the creator of that lib. But can you confirm if js sdk will work without a wrapper

Comment: The JS SDK should work on Android, but iOS Safari/Webview does not support WebRTC yet, so it won't work there.

Comment: @philnash Will the Twilio Programmable Video JavaScript SDK work for React Native now? I know that Safari finally supports WebRTC, but I don't want to use a Webview anyway - and I want transmit audio and video from phone to phone or from desktop web to phone. Thanks.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill there is a community built package for [Twilio Video in React Native](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc) that might help you out.

Comment: @philnash Thanks. I opened an issue there, but would you happen to know whether that package stays up to date with the latest Twilio API changes?

Comment: @JamieCorkhill I haven't used it I'm afraid, so I can't make any guarantees about it. The last updates were only a couple of months ago though, so that's promising.

Comment: @philnash In `twilio-video.js`, one of your developers stated that a React Native SDK was in the works and even granted read access to others. See issue 510 (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/510). Would you happen to know anything about that? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, a React Native SDK is still coming. I see you've posted on that thread, it's the best place to get in touch with the team and get early access. I don't have any more news than that though.

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering the same thing before trying to build/experiment, they have no plans in supporting cross-platform SDKs as of 3 months ago. I found the answer here:

https://twilioinc.wpengine.com/2015/05/getting-started-with-twilio-video.html#comment-2613693341